# "good lay in" --> what does "in" stand for here?

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis, colloquialisms, ellipses

What is the exact function of the word "in" here?

> Richard, I’ve had the last good lay **in** an old whore, and it had to be in front of the mirror.

For the context of this sentence, see [this article](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2013/04/15/the-spy-who-liked-me).

I have two explanations:

(1) "in", used here, is short for "in the person of". So the sentence would read:

> Richard, I’ve had the last good lay **in the person of** an old whore, and it had to be in front of the mirror.

(2) Or is "in" short for the act of penetrating your partner during intercourse?

"I have spent quality time in her." = the speaker has had sex with a partner and he had fun.

So the sentence would read:

> Richard, I’ve had the last good lay **inside** an old whore, and it had to be in front of the mirror.

---

- Which of the two readings is correct? Or do neither explain the proper function of "in"? If that is the case, what is the real function of "in"?
- The usual way of putting it would be "laid with an old whore", but instead of "with", "in" is used. Why?

Comment: Have you tried a good dictionary? Or two?

Comment: Use comments only to [ask for clarification, suggest improvements, or offer short-lived information](/help/privileges/comment). Do not use comments to answer (post an [answer](/help/how-to-answer) instead), praise or rebuke ([vote](/help/why-vote) instead), discuss ([chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) instead), suggest edits ([edit](/help/privileges/edit) instead), or comment on site design or policy (post at [meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/) instead).

Comment: Could we drop the irrelevancies, please?

Isn’t *the last good lay in an old whore* clear enough?

Either way, the whore should be compared to a room or building. In neither the whore nor the building could it matter what you did.

If *in*, here, was short for anything that would be not the *person* but the *body*.

Would you say *I sat in…* or *I sat inside the room*? 


*In* is not short for anything, including *the act of penetrating your partner during intercourse*.

*I spent (quality) time in her* and *the speaker had sex with a partner and had fun* have no place here.

Comment: @MetaEd Hi, I understand, thanks. But now all comments are gone. You might want to update the original post next time **before** deleting all comments, this way only the irrelevant part of the discussion gets lost. (Or is there a way of searching for deleted comments?)

Comment: This is not a discussion page. Discussion is welcome in [chat].